# random numbers with seed

Tags: c#, algorithm, unity-game-engine

Currently I'm developing a game using C# and Unity3d for my project at school

I'm trying to figure out how to generate random numbers based on a specific number. My Game Runs like this for example you were given a base number of "6", I need some tips on how to generate possible combination of numbers based on number "6" using addition for example it will generate numbers `2+2+2 = 6` or `1+1+4 = 6` or `3+3 = 6` and so on

Currently I am using this code to generate random number but i have no idea how to make it generate random number based on a seed

```
randNumber = Mathf.RoundToInt(Random.Range(0.0f,8.0f));
```

need help thx in advance sorry just a newbie

Comment: Can you please be clearer on what you are asking?  Are you asking for a way to generate random sums that add up to a certain number or are you asking how to seed the random number generator?

Comment: @simeon pilgrim, to be exact i need to generate possible combination of random numbers based on a base number (addition process)

for example. In my game lvl 1. the base number is "5" (i need to generate possible random numbers that when sum up will produce a value of 5) 

(2+3=5)
(1+2+2=5)
(1+1+1+2=5)

and so on
btw thx for the reply!! 
sorry if its very confusing

Comment: but if you target number is an int and between 0 and 8, then is a fixed number of values that sum to each target. No Random involved. So is you 'problem' related to unity and random number, if not remove that stuff, is your 'problem' is about find numbers that sum to X, if not remove that. And by 'problem' what do you need help with, all of my homework is not the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Randomly pick a number from 1 to the number, add it to a list, and then subtract the drawn number.  Repeat until the number reaches 0.  Here is an example:

```
  static Random rand = new Random();

  private static List<int> GetRandomNums(int number)
  {
     List<int> list = new List<int>();
     while (number != 0)
     {
        int addend = rand.Next(1, number + 1);
        list.Add(addend);
        number -= addend;
     }
     return list;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is a pseudo code :-

```
randlist = []

int target = 5;

while(target > 0) {

 int rand = Random(1,target);
 target = target-rand;
 randlist.add(rand);
}

print randlist
```

**Note:-** `Random(1,target)` generates a random number between (1,target) both inclusive.